# nginx phpmyadmin access denied on themes folder

Tags: php, nginx, phpmyadmin

```
location /phpmyadmin/ {
    allow all;
    root /opt/data;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO         $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

this is my config ngnix for phpmyadmin, it is working, but the subfolders with images/css/js in the themes folder are "access denied", i've tried to set it to `chmod 777`, but it didnt helped, any hint please?